# static route configuration?

Tags: networking, cisco, configuration, static-routes

i rewiew my router configuration and i found :-

`ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Serial1/0:1`

`ip route 10.0.14.31 255.255.255.255 FastEthernet0/0`

what we mean by two command ??? and what we mean by `255.255.255.255` and `0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's dissect this one line at a time.

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Serial1/0:1
```

The first ip route command will dictate Serial1/0:1 as a default interface for all packet routing.

```
ip route 10.0.14.31 255.255.255.255 FastEthernet0/0
```

The second ip route command dictates that any network packet that is seeking for a destination address that's within the range of 10.0.14.31/255.255.255.255 will be routed through FastEthernet0/0

The value of `255.255.255.255` is a subnet mask value. It is a deterministic value that defines that scope of the network that your router has been assigned to handle.

Comment: I would just add to to Michael's excellent response that the mask 255.255.255.255 is called a host mask and specifies a single network device.